# NodeManager NameNode ResourceManager DataNode SecondaryNameNode not running

Tags: hadoop

i followed this link to install hadoop http://thepowerofdata.io/setting-up-a-apache-hadoop-2-7-single-node-on-ubuntu-14-04/

at the end when i run

`jps`

the output I get is

`12815 JPS`

But according to the link I should be getting 
    `Jps
    NodeManager
    NameNode
    ResourceManager
    DataNode
    SecondaryNameNode`

I also tried to run the daemons manually by commands 
    
    `hadoop-daemon.sh start namenode
    hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
    yarn-daemon.sh start resourcemanager
    yarn-daemon.sh start nodemanager
    mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh start historyserver`

but I get [fatal error] like this
    
    `starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/lib/hadoop-2.7.0/logs/hadoop-hadoop-namenode-akshay-300E4Z-300E5Z-300E7Z.out
    [Fatal Error] core-site.xml:21:2: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.`

please help.

Comment: Check that your `core-site.xml`  file is well formed XML file. See what is in the line 21, second character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In core-site.xml I changed "`fs.default.name`" to "`fs.defaultFS`" but yet it was showing errors at some line number. I gone through the hadoop configuration files in editor where I found out that I have used the tag "`<configuration>...</configuration>`"
twice in cases of all 4 .xml files (core-site,mapred-site,yarn-site,hdfs-site)(as I had just copy pasted from online source)

after removing it I ran the commands

```
hadoop namenode -format
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
jps
```

and finally i got the required response

```
4098 DataNode
4660 SecondaryNameNode
5271 Jps
4968 NodeManager
4829 ResourceManager
3933 NameNode
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Remove all dfs content =>  rm -rf /tmp/< userName>/dfs/*

2-hadoop namenode -format

3-$HADOOP_HOME/sbin/start-all.sh

3- jps